# How to set default category based on current weekly day in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

1. My site is comthainguyen.tk built with WordPress.
2. You can see on left sidebar have Food Menu: Monday/TuesDay/... (this is Categories type).
3. I want when users navigate to my Homepage URL (comthainguyen.tk), the category of current day will auto choose (click). I mean if today is Monday then Monday category will be chosen, and Tuesday then Tuesday category will be chosen, ....

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the issue you are facing? Please see here on how to ask a question in SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Given that you are asking people to go to your website and look at it, this is firmly off-topic. The problem is that once you have fixed it, this question will have no educational or informational value for new readers. Please add everything readers need to see, _in the question itself_.

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Thanks for deleting your supplementary material provided as an answer (8 hours ago). In general I would recommend that you add that to your question straight away, rather than risking question closure in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're thinking about this a tad wrong. You don't necessarily need/want to "auto-click" on the category. Just redirect to the appropriate category on based on the date.

Just make use the the current day with PHP's `date()` function, use `wp_safe_redirect()` to redirect to the category using the day you just got, and wrap that all with `is_front_page()` to make sure it's only fired if it's for the home page.

Now all requests to the home page will get redirected to the current days' category instead. Something like this should get you started:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'load_category_by_day' );
function load_category_by_day(){
    if( is_front_page() ){
        $current_day = strtolower( date('l') ); // 'monday', 'sunday', etc.

        wp_safe_redirect( site_url( "/category/$current_day/" ) ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! i am learning about wordpress :) still are noob. So i just copy and paste your code to function.php is enough?

Comment: My pleasure! Yes that should be sufficient, just paste it into your `functions.php` file and it should work right away

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work, pls see the screenshot link https://prnt.sc/keju3z (safe)
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry but what exactly am I looking at in the screenshot? Also note you should be esceptioally careful with the Appearance Editor, ESPECIALLY for the functions.php file - consider using an FTP/sFTP client like FileZilla!

Comment: yes. i will try FileZilla, all i need is paste: 
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'load_category_by_day' );

function load_category_by_day(){
if( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ){
    $current_day = strtolower( date('N') ); // 'monday', 'sunday', etc.

    wp_safe_redirect( site_url( "/category/$current_day/" ) ); 
}
}
?>
right?

Comment: do i need : do_action ? Thanks!

Comment: i tried with filezila, but your code not run. Do u have any suggestion ?

Comment: Hey my apologies but I accidentally had it on the wrong hook (I also had the wrong date format string) - I've updated the code and tested it on one of my sites and it's working as it should now

Comment: Thank you so much, so much! i got it :) :) I am very happy now (Y) Good luck for all (Y)